# How to echo onclick location href

Tags: javascript, echo, location-href

This is the link that i have:

```
echo '<li><a class="thickbox badge-upload-selector badge-upload-url" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="location.href="#TB_inline?width=450&height=350&inlineId=addfromurl" title="URL DE IMAGEN/VIDEO">Agregar URL</a></li>';
```

This replace the displayed link value from status and set it to javascript:void(0) but the link in location.href its not working.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just put the link as the `href` attribute?  Why do you need an `onclick` event here?  `href="#TB_inline?width=450&height=350&inlineId=addfromurl"`

Comment: because i want to hide it from the status window with javascript:void(0)

Comment: So, you want the link to to go a page, but you don't want the user to see the URL in their address bar?

Comment: Your HTML syntax is incorrect. You should replace `onclick="location.href="xxx"` with `onclick="location.href='xxx'"`.

Comment: This is what happen when i do that -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: @Oscar - My mistake; I missaw you're using PHP for that. You have to escape the `'` like so: `onclick="location.href=\'xxx\'"`.